# How to use ASP.NET Core Antiforgery with AngularJS app on separate subdomain?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken

I have an ASP.NET Core backend with some Web APIs, and an AngularJS client on separate subdomains (Actually on localhost with different ports), and I can't seem to get Antiforgery to work.

I get **400 Bad request** response on APIs protected with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken], this is my backend code :

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");

...

app.Use(next => context => {
    tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
    context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false });
    return next(context);
});
```

First problem i've got is that the cookie is not set on my AngularJS app, i've resolved it by setting WithCredentials to true : `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;`

The second one is that the X-XSRF-TOKEN header is not set automatically by AngularJS, and i've solved it by setting an interceptor : `config.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = $cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN');`

Now I can receive the token and send it with my $http requests, I don't understand why API calls are rejected ! Is it related that the applications are not on the same port ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? If so, please help me to fix this..

Comment: Same issue for me also.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
config.headers['XSRF-TOKEN'] = $cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]** instead of **[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]**

**ValidateAntiForgeryToken:** This filter validates the request token on each and every method it is placed on, regardless of the HTTP verb. So it even validates GET and HEAD requests where there is no antifrogery token to validate so causes **400 bad request**.

**AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute:** AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken is almost similar to ValidateAntiforgeryToken except for the fact that it doesn’t validate tokens on GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, and TRACE requests.

Generally, a controller may contain GET as well as POST action methods. POST action methods require validating the anti-forgery token and not the GET action methods. So, if the ValidateAntiforgeryToken is declared on the controller, the HTTP GET requests become invalid, it would throw an error.
AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken can be used in such case.

Sometimes it is not required that you validate all the tokens, for example, with requests like:

GET

HEAD

OPTIONS

TRACE

AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken should be used in such cases.

*`It is advisable to use AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute rather than using ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute globally because if we apply ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute globally then we will get error in case of requests like GET, HEAD, TRACE, etc. becuase in such request server does not receive the anti-forgery tokens which will cause validation errors for those requests.`*

Sometimes there might be some requirements for ignoring the anti-forgery tokens or you need to ignore the tokens for specific actions of the controllers. In such cases, you can use an **IgnoreAntiforgeryToken** filter.